# invoke sql function using nhibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I want to query like this:

```
select * from table where concat(',', ServiceCodes, ',') like '%,33,%';
select * from table where  (','||ServiceCodes||',') like '%,33,%';
```

so, I wrote this code:

```
ICriteria cri = NHibernateSessionReader.CreateCriteria(typeof(ConfigTemplateList));
cri.Add(Restrictions.Like(Projections.SqlFunction("concat", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("ServiceCodes")), "%,33,%"));
```

I get sql similar :

```
select * from table where  (ServiceCodes) like '%,33,%';
```

But it is not what I want，how to do it???
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were in the right track, but you forgot to add what you wanted to concat.

Try this:

```
cri.Add(Restrictions.Like(
            Projections.SqlFunction("concat",
                                    NHibernateUtil.String,
                                    Projections.Constant(","), 
                                    Projections.Property("ServiceCodes"),
                                    Projections.Constant(",")),
        "%,33,%"));
```