# NHibernate / MySQL string concatenation

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a nhibernate linq query that looks like this:

```
 from b in session.Query<Bookmark>()
where b.Uri.Equals(uri) ||
      b.Uri.Equals("www." + uri) ||
string.Concat("www.", b.Uri).Equals(uri)
select b
```

This blows up, saying Concat isn't support, but when I change it to

```
 from b in session.Query<Bookmark>()
where b.Uri.Equals(uri) ||
      b.Uri.Equals("www." + uri) ||
      ("www." + b.Uri).Equals(uri)
select b
```

It runs fine, but the query looks like this:

```
select cast(count(*) as SIGNED) as col_0_0_ 
 from bookmarks bookmark0_ 
 where bookmark0_.Uri = 'www.google.com' 
    or bookmark0_.Uri = 'www.www.google.com'
    or 'www.'+bookmark0_.Uri = 'www.google.com';
```

Where the 'www.'+bookmark0_.Uri is "added" instead of concat('www.',bookmark0_.Uri).  Is there a way to concatenate strings in Linq for NHibernate for MySQL?

Comment: see correct answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680116/invoke-sql-function-using-nhibernate), but they're using criteria api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is an HqlGenerator that solves this problem:

```
public class ConcatHqlGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public ConcatHqlGenerator()
        : base()
    {
        this.SupportedMethods = new[] 
        { ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => string.Concat(null, null)) };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method,
Expression targetObject,
ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments,
HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder,
IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.Concat(
            new[] 
            {
                visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),
                visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression()
            });
    }
}
```

Add this to your HQLGeneratorsRegistry and you will be good to go with calls to string.Concat in you LINQ statements.

```
public class LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
        : base()
    {
        this.Merge(new ConcatHqlGenerator());
    }
}
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    var configuration = new NHib.Cfg.Configuration();
    configuration.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg
                                           .Environment.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry, 
typeof(LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry).AssemblyQualifiedName);
    configuration.Configure();
    return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: This solution got the query from b in session.Query<Bookmark>()
where b.Uri.Equals(uri) ||
      b.Uri.Equals("www." + uri) ||
string.Concat("www.", b.Uri).Equals(uri)
select b; to work, Thanks Travis!

Comment: If you are using something other than string this will work: treeBuilder.Cast(visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),typeof(string))

Comment: Or better yet: arguments[0].Type==typeof(string)? visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(): treeBuilder.Cast(visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),typeof(string))

Answer (score 0):

thats Because concatination of two types. May be you can try string.Concat("www" + b.Uri.ToString);

Comment: it appears that nhib linq knows nothing about function String.Concat, but it's expandable so you can implement Concat for linq to understand it

Comment: jjjjj, have you got a sample of how to write a linq overload function?

Comment: dipti-mehta, they are both of type string and in the database, uri is a varchar... The issue is with how mysql handles string concatenation, unlike SQL server, you must use the concat function which NHibernate doesn't seem to recognise in it's attempt at linq... Yet