# How to write an expression for string concatenation for linq?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

How to write an expression for string concatenation for linq?
I have this:

```
x => (x.Address1 + " " + x.Address2).Contains("add")
```

predicate and I don't know how to write a lambda expression for string concatenation without using `string.Concat` method. So I have two expressions (`x.Address1` and `" "`) and I need to concatenate them.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. What does string concatenating have to do with LINQ or lambda expressions? Why do you want to do it *"without using string.Concat"* (or the `+` operator)?

Comment: what's the issue? why you don't like string.Concat?

Comment: Are you trying to query NHibernate for objects that match the predicate? I'm just guessing because of the nhibernate tag.

Comment: I pass property in string format ("Address1 + ' ' + Address2"), operation (Contains) and value to the server and on the server I dynamically create predicate using expressions and pass this predicate to Where methond in nhibernate's linq. string.Concat method is not supported by nhibernate's linq. I know this because I got not supported exception when I tried to use string.Concat method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This link has the solution: [NHibernate / MySQL string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105340/nhibernate-mysql-string-concatenation)

Will the string `foo` in `.Contains(foo)` ever contain a space? If not, try Ade's second predicate as that avoids the concatenation.

If that doesn't work you might have to get more objects out of the database than you need and filter them in the code. If you have to do this it might be worth using an initial predicate like `x => x.Address1.Contains(foo[0]) || x.Address2.Contains(foo[0])` to limit the number of objects you get back. I leave it to you to come up with a better initial predicate than this.

Comment: I can't use such predicate x => x.Address1.Contains(foo[0]) || x.Address2.Contains(foo[0]) because my initial predicate might be more complex: x => (x.Address1+" "+x.Address2+" "x.City+", "+x.ZipCode).Contains("add") and I can have ==, StartWith, EndWith  instead of Contains. So I need to have an ability to concatenate dynamically properties and consts together using expressions.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105340/nhibernate-mysql-string-concatenation

Comment: Joey: your comment helped me a lot. Write this in the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why you wouldn't want to use String.Concat.  This works fine:

```
var foo = wibble.Select(s => String.Concat("foo", s, "bar"));
```

Going back to your example, wouldn't it be better to write `x => x.Address1.Contains("add") || x.Address2.Contains("add")`

Comment: As I wrote above I can't use string.Concat because I get not supported exception when I try to query NHibernate for objects.

Comment: Ah, in that case your question is about NHibernate's support for lambda expressions, rather than Linq in general.  This is common to ORMs, so I'd just stick with more primitive operations (i.e. just add the strings together) - the issue is basically that your ORM doesn't know how to translate String.Concat(foo, bar) into a SQL statement.