# How to specify linqtohql.generatorsregistry property in XML configuration file

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

It is not possible to specify linqtohql.generatorsregistry in session-factory section of NHibernate xml configuration file because the configuration file is not valid then. Where the property should be set in xml if not there? According to xsd of the configuration file there is not any other place where to put it.

Comment: Have you gotten any information on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing information gathering on this problem and I have no definite answer but here is what I got:

I am not sure this is possible based on: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/eUt7PRWOeAI

Rather than try to get this working in the config file, I tried the ISessionFactory and this seem to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271616/178550